# How can I use WiFi on my notebook computer?

Tags: wifi

After installing elementary OS (elementaryos-5.0-stable.20181016.iso / Juno) on a recently purchased notebook computer from HP, the device no longer has WiFi.

No wireless devices are found under Network Settings, only VPNs and Proxies. There are many suggested solutions for this problem with varying degrees of reported success.

This problem will significantly hinder any user switching from Windows, where most devices tend to work fairly seamlessly. This notebook is mostly useless without WiFi.

Is there a canonical resource available that a user should follow to get functioning WiFi?

Answer (score 0):

Please go to [appcenter](/questions/tagged/appcenter) over a Ethernet connection and click the `Installed` tab. If you see `bcmwl-kernel-source`, click on `free` to install it. Reboot your system and you will have wireless facility.

Comment: Thanks Hasan. This particular notebook doesn't have an ethernet adapter. Why isn't this included with installation?

Comment: Just wanted to note as well that I believe this notebook has a realtek wireless adaptor.

Comment: You can download `bcmwl-kerner-source` in some other computer and install it manually i guess.

Comment: What command in terminal shows? sudo update-initramfs -u It should show the information about the missing firmware. Can you provide the output of this command? Linux by default does not work like Windows. It does not recognize hardware and install the firmware (driver) for Wi-Fi adapters and sound cards. Of course some generic drivers are included however not everyone. By default Linux is a server system and was adapted by many people or companies to a desktop environment. In server Wi-Fi or sound by default does not exist.